# Как ноды должны получать код маппера/редьюсера и входные/выходные данные?

Tags: map-reduce, кластер

Каким образом ноды должны получать код маппера/редьюсера и входные/выходные данные?

Answer (score 1):

Кластер абстрактный? Подсистема и язык значения не имеют?

*Если абстрактно - и то и другое обычно через сообщения, код - либо в виде бинарного кода целевой платформы (если кластер однородный), либо в виде исходного или промежуточного байткода для гетерогенного кластера.*